# apt-get gets "duplicate source entries" and two architectures

Tags: 11.10, apt, software-sources

Since I upgraded to Oneiric apt-get seems to ignore my architecture and gets the sources for both, amd64 AND i386, files from the repositoreis. this leads to constant "duplicate source entries" errors.

What to do?

**EDIT: Information provided by *dizzy*

Here is the requested file (since I'm not allowed to post more than two URLs I've modified the URLs not to be recognized (to *std url* / http:// to ..):

```
deb *std url* oneiric main restricted

deb *std url* oneiric-updates main restricted

deb *std url* oneiric universe
deb *std url* oneiric-updates universe

deb *std url* oneiric multiverse
deb *std url* oneiric-updates multiverse

deb ..archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner

deb *std url* oneiric-security main restricted
deb *std url* oneiric-security universe
deb *std url* oneiric-security multiverse

deb ..download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian oneiric contrib # disabled on upgrade to oneiric

deb ..extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main #Third party developers repository
```

Comment: Can you add the content of /etc/apt/sources.list to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They enabled multiarch support in Oneiric, which breaks aptitude, see this bug entry on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/831768